# Decentralised Identity System-blockchain- Ethereum

Tags: blockchain, decentralization, identity

I have to implement such system described in https://ethereum.org/en/decentralized-identity/
Are there any resources and examples I can refer to ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I think it's best to use an existing service out there. [Proof of Humanity](https://proofofhumanity.id/) does exactly that for you. It is the most established system out there yet and already well adapted. Here are the [docs](https://kleros.gitbook.io/docs/products/proof-of-humanity).

If you still want to build your own solution I would suggest you take a look at their [smart contracts](https://github.com/Proof-Of-Humanity/Proof-Of-Humanity) and skim through their [book](https://kleros.io/book.pdf).